# css: Unexpected margin / padding in Firefox 4 css

Tags: css, firefox, margin

I've recently started to setup a website and ran into a problem in firefox 4.
My main navigation bar has an  unexpected margin from the top of the page.
- Only in Firefox 4.
Chrome, IE8, IE9, IE7, Safari work fine. Only FF4 seems to bug around.
How can I solve this elegantly without cluttering my css with ff hacks?

Thanks for your adive:

URL for live demo: http://www.creativeworkx.at

Answer (score 1):

The `2em` margin from the `#main-wrap` div are causing it.

Adding `margin-top: -2em` to your `#doc` div fixes.

Comment: Thank you, I was too blind to see. But why FF only?

Comment: Due to quirks mode. Provide a proper Doctype and FF will behave more strictly.

Comment: Why quirks? This is the normal html 5 tag?

Comment: @Cobra_Fast The Doctype seems to be fine, it is `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: Web Developer Extension tells my this doctype is standards compliant?

Comment: I dont't get it. #main-wrap is not wrapped around #top wrap. how can #main-wrap cause a margin from the very top of the page to #top-wrap?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'd call it a bug. You might should report it to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi and see what they say.

Answer (score 0):

This css is the badguy:

```
#main-wrap {
    margin: 2em auto auto;
}
```

Comment: I dont't get it. #main-wrap is not wrapped around #top wrap. how can #main-wrap cause a margin from the very top of the page to #top-wrap?

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out a simple test for your case:

```
<div style="float:left;">test</div><div style="margin-top: 50px;"></div>
```

**Note:** Setting `margin-bottom` instead of `margin-top` acts similar but can be solved by adding contents into the second `DIV`

It shows that it's a kind of complicated `float` problem which cause an unexpected rendering.

This unexpected rendering even appears in browser besides Firefox, like Chrome.

---

However, I've recently find a quick, but not formal solution, to solve your interesting problem unpredictably.

Just add a text, no matter empty string or `&nbsp;` after the menu, the first DIV or before the DIVs which have margin.

You can wrap the text by an element with a property of zero height and block display.

Like:

```
<div style="height:0">&nbsp;</div>
```

The problem will look like solved by this trick. **:-)**

Enjoy the fun of writing CSS. **:-)**